# How to delete or disable the virtual controller IP from the Aruba master IAP?

Tags: wap

I have applied the virtual-controller-IP on my master IAP and configuration is persisted on my master IAP which can be viewed in the running configuration of the IAP.

```
WAP# configure terminal  WAP (config) # virtual-controller-ip 200.20.200.237  
WAP (config) # end  
WAP# commit apply  
committing configuration... 
configuration committed.  
WAP# reload all  
Do you really want to reset the system (y/n): y
```

How to delete or disable this applied configuration using Aruba CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To disable or unset a Virtual Controller IP we need to apply virtual-controller-ip as 0.0.0.0 in the master wap or Virtual controller.**

Let's apply virtual-controller-ip as 0.0.0.0 in master WAP.

```
WAP# configure terminal
We now support CLI commit model, please type "commit apply" for configuration to take effect.
WAP (config) # virtual-controller-ip 0.0.0.0
WAP (config) # end
WAP# commit apply no-save
committing configuration...
```

Now in the master wap running-config we don't have virtual-controller-ip.

```
WAP# show running-config
virtual-controller-country US
```

From Aruba 8.3 MIB, it says when the Virtual controller IP address is not set, it will return 0.0.0.0.

```
   aiVirtualControllerIPAddress OBJECT-TYPE
       SYNTAX      IpAddress 
       MAX-ACCESS  read-only
       STATUS      current
       DESCRIPTION
            "Virtual Controller IP Address. If this is not set, returns 0.0.0.0"
       ::= { aiInfoGroup 5 }
```